Why isn't there financial safety if I am arrested illegally?
I have been arrested approximately 14 times in my life and never Mirandized. The last time I was arrested, about 8 police officers stood around me asking me what I was doing. After I explained every action I took in thorough detail, one of them said, "You are under arrest." I asked, "On what charge?" He answered me: "Detained." No further words were spoken.
In jail I was separated from my financial obligations. I lost my apartment, many of my things, my cell phone number, and my ability to pay my credit card and other bills on time. Now I have delinquency on my credit report in Experian keeping me from acceptance of any credit card applications, even a business credit card. I was never tried and I was remediated to psychiatric treatment where there is an outstanding bill. Why should I have to suffer financial loss for an arrest that did not lead to a conviction?

Worth noting: Nothing you've described here suggests you were arrested illegally. There's really not anything illegal about arresting someone without reading them their Miranda rights.

Also worth noting: If you were arrested illegally, there are financial remedies through a civil actions for malicious prosecution, abuse of process, and violations of your civil rights.

How long were you arrested for without being charged?  In most countries, there's a limit to how long you may be held without charge, though I'm not sure what remedies are available.

This might be better asked on Politics SE. You do have some rights to obtain compensation, depending on where you are, but often it's not easy - because it's not in the state's interest to hand money out even if it's legitimate. In particular, giving money to people accused of crimes is often characterised by populists as "they're giving your hard-earned money to criminals/immigrants/other groups they love to hate" - so politics. And people think "It won't happen to me." It's inevitable that some innocent people will be arrested, but most states deal poorly with such people, for those reasons.

@Tom Has "Miranda" become a generic international term for informing someone of their rights? I know other countries have similar processes, but I didn't think they used the name of the US Supreme Court ruling to refer to it.

This seems like it's better answered on Politics.SE.

How long is one thing, how frequent is another thing. Now this question shows that it's quite easy for law enforcement to harass people: arrest them, detain them just slightly less than the maximum period, release them, and then arrest them again.

Is it unreasonable to ask whether you were found guilty of any charges the other 13 times you were arrested?  While an arrest that ends up being unnecessary is unfortunate and I would feel sympathy for someone who suffered financially, it also seems unreasonable to expect that you were unlawfully arrested 14 different times

I agree there's a "fool me once, shame on you, fool me twice, shame on me" thing going on here.  After about the 3rd arrest I'd expect a 4th and do two things:  rethink life choices, and have an attorney on retainer who will pull in an accountant to make sure your bills get paid.   Freedom isn't free.  @Tom "Miranda" applies in USA and establishes nationality.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica While the assumption that the OP has made some poor decisions seems reasonable, I think we can point to many cases in history where people have been treated unfairly by police for reasons that most rational people would agree are illegitimate abuses of power. I think it's worth considering that in this context and what protections exist for people in such scenarios. What's to stop a police force from ruining someone's career/life by arresting them repeatedly and then releasing them without charges?

@Harper-ReinstateMonica might be bad life choices, or might be a case of "arrest the usual suspects". It is well documented that members of certain ethnicities living in certain areas are subject to more police scrutiny than people of a different ethnicity living in different areas.

@JimmyJames There is NO assumption that the OP has made some poor decisions. You are making a hostile or cynical inference from "rethink".  Rethink means exactly what it says, and a very common outcome is "I confirmed my life choices are reasonable".  In other words I'm not saying OP is in the wrong, I'm saying OP should find out definitely, positively, one way or the other, so they can adjust their actions as needed to stop the pattern. E.G. relocate to get out of a corrupt jurisdiction.

@Tom and JimmyJames, "fool me once shame on you, fool me twice shame on me" refers specifically to a case where if you are dealing with a police force that behaves unexpectedly or improperly, the first time they do it, you had no reason to believe they do that, so you are not an author of what follows.   But now you know they do that, you need to adjust your behavior otherwise you are an author of the repeat.

The answer is basically, "because the law isn't fair".
Arguments that this is a 5th Amendment taking or that there is some other reason that you have a right to compensation have been rejected by the courts.
There was really no decisive point at which this became the rule. It's just the way that it always was, and for the most part, no one has had the political will to change the law. People who are likely to become acquitted criminal defendants, and people who are likely to be arrested but released without being charged, have lousy lobbyists and aren't a well organized group of people.
There are some very narrow exceptions to the general rule that there is no compensation in these cases, on a state by state basis. These statutes are summarized at Law.SE answers here, here, and here.
But the general rule is that you don't get compensation for the costs of a constitutionally conducted arrest or criminal proceeding that doesn't result in a conviction, even if this is terribly unfair.
If law enforcement intentionally acts in a manner that violates the constitution, and other procedural hurdles are overcome, you can sue the government under 42 U.S.C. § 1983 for your economic and non-economic damages and attorneys' fees that were caused by the violations of the constitution that took place. But proving this kind of case is hard, and the costs of litigation usually dwarf the economic harm you have suffered. So, attorneys usually take on these cases only when there is a death or lengthy incarceration or other extreme harm involved.
And, there are lots of routine and perfectly constitutional circumstances in which you can be lawfully arrested or tried for an offense for which you aren't guilty that doesn't result in a criminal conviction. I have personally advocated for changes in this area of law, but I'm one lonely voice among millions of people.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I would recommend adding a small blurb regarding Miranda Rights for completeness. Specifically that Miranda Rights are not required to be read for an arrest and subsequent jailing. They are only required for questioning someone in police custody. Or that they are unrelated to the outcome the question seeks.

I suggest this is a political outcome, based on the belief that giving police more power helps society.  People are extremely surprised when they have to interact with the legal system how punitive being arrested is, even without charges.  Police in most states in the US are allowed to hold someone for 48 hours without any charges, and if you complain about it you're just more likely to actually be charged.  Your opportunity for redress is almost zero.
This is the result of "tough on crime" politicians, and the fact that in the US only some communities are actively policed, so most people have zero interaction with law enforcement outside of traffic violations.

I would agree with the final sentence, excepting to add that IMO even those interactions are very minimal these days. I know watching videos of chases, etc, are quite popular, but I don't remember the last time I saw an actual traffic stop not related to an accident.

Maybe it's regional, @CGCampbell, but I see non-accident-related traffic stops relatively frequently along my daily commute, and I have personally been the subject of one (for perfectly good reason) within the last couple of years.

And of course there are always exceptions — like the interior of any major city (well... maybe not LA), where only a tiny fraction of police activity involves motor vehicle enforcement.

sweden
The Act (1998:714) on compensation for detention and other coercive measures establishes a right to compensation from the Government for those who have been detained for more than 24 hours without a subsequent conviction. Compensation can be granted for expenses, lost income, disruption of business, and emotional distress. Compensation is typically granted through an out-of-court settlement after a written application has been submitted to the Chancellor of Justice, but if the applicant is not happy with the Chancellor's decision, they can take their case to the courts.
According to the website of the Chancellor of Justice, the compensation for emotional distress is normally 30,000 SEK (~US$2,800) per month for the first month, 20,000 SEK (~US$1,900) per month for month 2-6, and then gradually increasing for subsequent months going as high as 100,000 SEK (~US$9,300) per month after 10 years. The compensation for emotional distress can be increased if the detainee was very young or suspected of a particularly serious crime.

Spain also pays compensation for preventive prison if there is no conviction, but I do not know the details.

It might even be required from all EU countries in some form.

@VladimirFГероямслава It seems there isn't. Further reading: https://eucrim.eu/articles/compensation-for-unjustified-detention-and-the-european-arrest-warrant/
